# Redirecting the last line of an application's output to a file every time a new output is being returned

Tags: linux, bash, shell, redirect, output

I am trying to store only the last line of the output of a running application in a file, replacing the contents of the file every time the applications returns a new output with the value of the last message outputted. For example, if a running application `helloworld` produces the following output:

```
Message1
Message2
Message3
Message4
```

And I am running the application like:

```
$ ./helloworld > output.txt
```

I want the `output.txt` file to always store the last message, so it will first contain:

```
Message1
```

Then when the application returns `Message2` the contents of the file will be:

```
Message2
```

And so on. The file contents will basically only have one line at any given time.

Comment: how could we know that info is from one message or another ? (1 message = 1 line ?)

Comment: `$ ./helloworld >> output.txt` Using `'>>'` appends to the new file, while `'>'` truncates the existing file and stores only new data starting with a new file each time. So what you actually want is exactly what your are doing `$ ./helloworld > output.txt` will do just that. If you want to double-truncate the file just to make sure, then `$ :> output.txt; ./helloworld > output.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write loop that reads from `stdin` and writes to output file.

```
helloworld | while read i; do echo $i > output.txt; done
```

Comment: Thanks you, this works perfectly. I have another related question. I am trying to start `helloworld`in background using `nohup`, and storing the PID of the process in a file too, using: `nohup helloworld | while read i; do echo $i > /tmp/helloworld.log; done 2>&1 & echo $! > /tmp/helloworld.pid`. Currently the PID being stored belongs to another process (the while loop I suppose). Any way to achieve this?

Comment: It belongs to `nohup` (which should not be a problem, killing it kills the process too).